# Save a Mongo ObjectId into another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on a [commenting system saved into Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/#schema) which suggests the following structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    discussion_id: ObjectId(...),
    slug: '34db',
    posted: ISODateTime(...),
    author: {
              id: ObjectId(...),
              name: 'Rick'
             },
    text: 'This is so bogus ... '
}
```

I would like to save the `author.id` as the `ObjectId` of the user commenting, I have this value in the request `req.user._id`

What data type do I need to give my Comment model to accept this value?

I tried:

```
const authorSchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  username: String
});
```

But this gives `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`

I see [ObjectId listed as a valid Schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) However, it appears only if  auto-generated.

What is the correct way to store the `user._id` ObjectId inside of the comment as `author.id`, OR is there a better way to store the reference entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have to define ObjectId in your schema file by getting it from Mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;
```

There's a full example of doing references in the docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)